# ImageMagick, MAMP 3, OS X

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, mamp-pro

After installing Yosemite MAMP 2 wasn't working properly. So I installed MAMP 3. Suddenly ImageMagick wasn't working anymore. After reinstalling and trying out every other fix I found on the internet it still doesn't work.

I'll tried:

in php.ini:

```
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php53-imagick/3.1.0RC2/imagick.so"
```

in envvars:

```
cDYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Hope somebody could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha! I found a solution!

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/convert /usr/bin/convert
```

This did the job for me. No editing of envars or php.ini.